# Why are android asset files not read by app?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-webview

I have a javascript file (ParameterFunctions.js) which isn't making it to the device for some reason.

It's definitely in the project:

[image: Android Studio File List]

I extracted the apk and it's definitely inside of it:
[image: Extracted apk contents]

When I look at the files on the device is doesn't exist:
[image: File list in webview debugger]

Why is this happening and how do I fix it? I've tried:

- Invalidate caches and restart
- Uninstall and reinstalled
- Sync project with file system
- Sync project with gradle files
- Reboot the device (both before and after reinstalling)

Comment: `When I look at the files on the device is doesn't exist:` Which app/application is displaying that on Android or PC?

Comment: @blackapps do you mean how am I looking at those files? Chrome: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews.

Comment: Mmm... that is all new for me. Debugging with a WebView using Chrome. But then more if it can look in assets. If it is in the apk then it should be in the assets of the installed app. But why do you take Chrome? I would just try to open an InputStream for a file in assets. Or list the assets/webfile/controllers/functions directory.

Comment: Chrome is specifically for debugging webviews. Asset files aren't directly on the SDCard, they're inside the application. You can't browse to them via ADB or Android Studio. I suppose my next test needs to be opening it programatically just to see if it actually exists on the device. That won't help fix the problem but would at least give more info.

Comment: Yes that is what i suggested: open it programmatically.

Comment: Opening it programatically does absolutely nothing to fix the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. There was a syntax error in the js file I was trying to include. Rather than report it Android decided that the entire file shouldn't be recognized.